# Algolia extension error in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, reindex, algolia, algolia-search

I have installed the Algolia search extension on the Magento2 website.

Upon reindexing, I am getting below error.

> "upgrade your plan or delete existing records".

My question is an upgraded plan we don't like to go because, we have around max 2k products, so the basic plan is enough for it.

For the second option "**Delete existing record**"

How to delete the existing records? Does that mean to delete the products?

Can anyone help me to resolve this issue?

I checked with extension support, they suggested me to post a query here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One of the possible solution for this

> Remove inactive products

In case there are products indexed in Algolia, which are not supposed to be there, they can be removed by running algolia_delete_products indexer:

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex algolia_delete_products
```

This indexer will `remove all products` from `Algolia indices`, which shouldn’t be displayed in search. This come in handy in case some products were disabled or deleted directly in Magento’s database and the extension could reindex and remove them regularly.

Reference: https://www.algolia.com/doc/integration/magento-2/how-it-works/indexing/

**I hope this will help**

Comment: hi Hasham. you mean by running above command, will it delete products from magento? is there any effect on db? because i am working on directly on live db

Comment: Yes according to algolia documentation, it will remove inactive products. I added the reference as well

Comment: It will remove from magento db? That shouldn't happen is it? if some products are  disabled intensionally, then they will be deleted

Comment: I already mentioned it in answer.

Comment: Yes u mentioned in answer, will it delete from Algolia indices or from magento database?